If i have the same project on 2 Remote git platforms, but 1 is several commits behind, what is the correct way to catch up?
I had a project on something other than github, I did a cloning and now the Project is in both places, same name and all, but because I made a mistake, the github repository is now missing many commits that I did to the other one.
I'm in intellij and don't know how to push the commits that were already pushed to the other to github so they are both equal. I do have now the right way to make a commit to both github and the other git repository at the same time but this doesn't solve that one repo is several commits behind.
Before someone asks, no I can't do the cloning repo thing as i did it again, i just need a way to push the commits that were already pushed to the new remote.
Thanks for your time.
Edit: Solved, it's this How pull changes from github to bitbucket after initial import?

What have you tried and what were the errors? I am asking because "I only have to push branch  to " amounts to a trivial git push <insert remote URL here> <X>.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+multiple+remotes
